# Cannot send custom http headers via Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, wcf, http-headers

I'm trying to send a GET request to a wcf server. I need to add a header in the request.
I tried the following code but using fiddler I see that the header is never sent.

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url + '?callback=?', 
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function (request) { //the old way
                request.setRequestHeader('cust-header', encodedString);
            },
            //headers: {
            //    'cust-header': encodedString
            //},
            data: parameters,
            success: function (data) {
                onSuccess(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            }
        });
```

I tried using the old way seting the header in "beforeSend" and then the new Ajax parameter "headers" but nothing seems to work.

I made the request via fiddler and it worked fine, any idea what I do wrong ?

Comment: Do you get back an error message ? no cross domain ? no "Allow origin" issue or what ?

Comment: Like it is there it works the get parameters are received but no header is sent not when I check the dev tools in chrome or fiddler.
If the request is sent without the callback I do receive a "405 Method Not Allowed" error from the server.